# how to move the camera in 3d space while animation is done in Manim

Tags: manim

I just want to move a sphere in a circle while showing it from different angles.
First from front, then from a side.

I tried this:

```
  from manim import *

 class ThreeDCameraRotation(ThreeDScene):
 def construct(self):
    self.camera.background_color = WHITE

    self.set_camera_orientation(phi=0 * DEGREES, theta=0* DEGREES)

    axes = ThreeDAxes()
    circle = Circle(radius=1, color=RED)

    self.add(circle, axes)

    sphere = Sphere(radius=0.1,color=RED).shift(RIGHT)
    #completed the setup

    self.play(MoveAlongPath(sphere, circle), run_time=3, rate_func=linear)
    #circular motion
    
    self.move_camera(phi=90 * DEGREES, theta=0 * DEGREES,run_time =2)
    #Camera movement 
    
    self.wait()

    self.move_camera(phi=0 * DEGREES, theta=0 * DEGREES)
    #again camera movement
    self.wait()
```

But the problem is  , the camera angle changes only after the rotation is finished.
But i want the sphere to keep rotating while it is shown from different angles.

How can i do this?
Please HELP

The purpose is to show Simple harmonic motion

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can do this:

**The Easy Way:**

The `ThreeDScene` has an effect called [ambient camera rotation](https://docs.manim.community/en/v0.14.0/reference/manim.scene.three_d_scene.ThreeDScene.html#manim.scene.three_d_scene.ThreeDScene.begin_ambient_camera_rotation). You use it in three steps:

1. Call the function `self.begin_ambient_camera_rotation(rate, about)`.
   This starts the camera rotating at the rate specified (in radians per second). There are three options for `about`: “theta”, “phi”, or “gamma”.
2. Play whatever animations you want. The camera will keep on rotating while this animations play.
3. Call `self.stop_ambient_camera_rotation(about)` and the camera will stop rotating.

In your case, you should do something like

```
self.begin_ambient_camera_rotation(90*DEGREES/3, about='phi')
self.play(MoveAlongPath(sphere, circle), run_time=3, rate_func=linear)
self.stop_ambient_camera_rotation(about='phi')
```

**The Way With More Control :**

If you want more control over the initial and final position of the camera, or if you don't want to figure out the rates of rotation, you can use `ValueTrackers`. The camera has a set of trackers that control its position, and you can access them with

```
self.camera.get_value_trackers()
```

which returns a list with trackers for phi, theta, the focal distance, gamma, and the distance to origin. You can do

```
self.play(tracker.animate.set_value(some_value), Some_other_animation())
```

to have the animation play at the same time as the camera moves to the specified position.

Try tweaking the this example to see how to use these trackers work:

```
class CameraTest(ThreeDScene):
  def construct(self):
    phi, theta, focal_distance, gamma, distance_to_origin = self.camera.get_value_trackers()

    self.add(ThreeDAxes())
    self.wait()
    self.play(phi.animate.set_value(50*DEGREES))
    self.play(theta.animate.set_value(50*DEGREES))
    self.play(gamma.animate.set_value(1))
    self.play(distance_to_origin.animate.set_value(2))
    self.play(focal_distance.animate.set_value(25))
    self.wait()
```